# Missing menu items in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, search, menu

I have two issues with my menu in ie8. If you visit this link http://betapwr.pokerworldratings.com/ in ie8 you'll see that the menu doesn't drop down under the "rooms" tab. I placed "overflow:visible" on everything containing it but no dice. the second problem is with a search bar that should be visible on the right which is missing. i checked the elements and didn't see anything wrong with "display". You can see the proper setup in Chrome. What am I missing?

Comment: There is a dodgy new line on line 11, menu.js ; you look for document.getElementById("nav") but there appears to be no such element - these errors will halt script processing in ie

Comment: Oh I see..you can actually see the sub menu appear in ie8 when I reduce the top margin. It just gets cut off at the bottom of the main menu which made me think it was an overflow issue but...

Comment: Error: illegal character
Source File: http://betapwr.pokerworldratings.com/wp-content/themes/pwr/js/menu.js
Line: 11, Column: 39
Source Code:
  this.className=this.className.replace�

Comment: The weird character after replace needs to be checked out. I don't know if this will fix it, but you should correct this error.

Comment: I got rid of the character but nothing changed. What should I change the document.getElementById("nav") too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your top menu is a all out of whack because you're not properly nesting your list items. You currently have this:

```
<li class="drop-work"><a href="#">Rooms</a>
   <ul>
      <a href=""><li>Room 1</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Room 2</li></a>
   </ul>
</li>
```

You're nesting some `a` tags as children of your list tag and that is not proper markup, so you can fix that part by formatting your submenu the right way:

**Fixed**

```
<li class="drop-work"><a href="#">Rooms</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="">Room 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Room 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Next, the html5.js shiv you're including in the header of your document is not found so your `header` and `footer` HTML5 tags are not actually being shivved properly in IE.

Now, your top menu works fine in IE8 but it looks bad in IE8 in compatibility mode, you can fix that by setting your list items to `display:inline` instead of display-block by using a css hack, like so:

.admin-menu ul li {
   *display:inline; /* this will target IE7 */
}

And then to stretch your `#admin-bar` to the left and right of your document you can modify your rule to the following:

```
#admin-bar {
    overflow:visible;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 99999;
    background:url(images/top-menu.png) repeat-x #000;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#0078CE 0,#006AAD 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#0078CE 0,#006AAD 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#0078CE 0,#006AAD 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#0078CE),color-stop(100%,#006AAD));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#0078CE 0,#006AAD 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#0078CE 0,#006AAD 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#0078CE',endColorstr='#006AAD');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#0078CE', endColorstr='#006AAD')";
    border-bottom:3px solid #005991;        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to straighten me out! Very much appreciated.